# How to mount Azure File share using domain user or system user

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-powershell

Please help to create code to mount the Azure file share using domain user.
Below is the code I write though I get message that "command completed successfully" but file share is not mounted.

```
$username = "domain\username"

$password = "Password"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword

Enable-PSRemoting -Force

$s = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://localhost:5985' -Credential $credential ``
    -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { ``
    net use Z: \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\^
        /u:AZURE\eysoacue2stdmediaint k/<storage-account-key>}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the command returns "command completed successfully", then most likely the drive got mapped, somewhere.

Mapped drives are specific to the user mapping the drive. For example, if you map a drive as an administrator, then a normal user won't see the drive. You need to do the mapping using the user account that will be using the drive.

You can get a list of mapped drives by running

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk -Namespace root\cimv2 | Where DriveType -eq 4
```

**Note**: this command is also relative to the user running it.

`DriveType` equals to 4 refers to network drives. See the [reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information regarding this parameter.

Comment: Yes, I found that NW drives are mounted but they are not connected properly. There is cross sign on all directories & when click any of them it gave error they drive not connected

Comment: Can someone plz help

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the script to mount from Azure Portal

[Azure Portal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUpYh.png)